# $R_1$ and $R_2$ are relations on $A$ and $R_1 \subseteq R_2$. $S_1, S_2$ are symmetric/transitive closures. Prove/disprove $S_1 \subseteq S_2$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $R_1$ and $R_2$ are relations on $A$ and $R_1 \subseteq R_2$.
>
> (a) Let $S_1,S_2$ be symmetric closures of $R_1$ and $R_2$,
> respectively. Is $S_1 \subseteq S_2$?
>
> (b) Let $S_1,S_2$ be transitive closures of $R_1$ and $R_2$,
> respectively. Is $S_1 \subseteq S_2$?

My attempt:

$(a)$

Take $(x,y) \in S_1$. Then either $(x,y) \in R_1$ or $(y,x) \in R_1$. Which means that either $(x,y) \in R_2$ or $(y,x) \in R_2$. Since $S_2$ is symmetric closure, we have $(x,y) \in S_2$. $(x,y)$ was arbitrary, hence $S_1 \subseteq S_2$

---

$(b)$ Take $(x,y) \in S_1$. Then either

1. $(x,y) \in R_1$

or

2. Exists some $a$ such that $(x,a) \in R_1$ and $(a,y) \in R_1$

**Case 1.**

$R_1 \subseteq R_2 \subseteq S_2$, hence $(x,y) \in S_2$

**Case 2.**

$R_1 \subseteq R_2$, hence $(x,a) \in R_2$ and $(a,y) \in R_2$. $S_2$ is transitive closure of $R_2$, hence $(x,y) \in S_2$.

Since $(x,y)$ was arbitrary, $S_1 \subseteq S_2$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Looks fine by me :)